# See Google Form results when not the owner

Tags: google-forms

I'd like to know if there was any way of seeing the results of a Google Form if you are not the owner. This would be important as I need to find out the results.

Answer (score 8):

If the owner enabled the ["Show a summary of responses" option](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2839588), you can see the results' **summary** in `https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/[form's ID]/viewanalytics`.

You can take the form's ID from the original form, which looks like `https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/[form's ID]/viewform`.

Comment: do u know how to view these responses in excel when you are not the owner. Please advice

Comment: You don't need to be the owner, you just need the owner to enable this option. If they did, each summary has a "Copy chart" button...which unfortunately only copies it as an image: https://ibb.co/jTWNLTj

Answer (score 4):

The owner, and any collaborators they have nominated, can choose to share the results with you.